# How to sell video or music streams with Magento?

Tags: downloadable

Is there a way to sell video or music streams with Magento and do it so that the stream address would be secure in a way that makes it impossible to redistribute the stream?

There does not seem to be an extension available for this particular need.

It would also be a huge plus if it would be possible to have some kind of monthly subscription option for registered customers so that they could access all videos sold in the store for limited time.

What you can do with basic Magento is to sell a downloadable video file, but it's not good enough for our needs. It might also be possible to sell an address to a static and encrypted html file that would load the stream, but this needs a bit tinkering to get it to work well enough and it might not be secure enough solution.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

There is no option to sell/rent video or music streams thru Magento, this is way beyond where it was build for. You should be able to build it with Magento, but the main logic should be build in the streaming solution.

To secure your streams you should use something like Wowza Media server or Adobe Media server, this makes it harder to capture the stream. Both servers also allow you to build an backend application to control the persons that are connecting (written in Java for Wowza, not sure what the Adobe Media server is using).

In the past I have build a solution to control the streams (you can both use it for live streams as for file streaming of audio or video) going thru the server. Based on the subscription model you can check when the client is connecting or every x time. This check can then connect to your Magento installation (using the SOAP/REST Api for example) and retreive the details for the client that is connecting (check if he ordered the correct product or something like that).

Answer (score 0):

There's a few extensions that might solve that problem. Here's a free one, a system integrator from the UK: [Meanbee](https://www.meanbee.com/magento-extensions/amazon-s3-downloadable-products.html)